# What is the alternative class of thumbnail of bootstrap 3 in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want thumbnail class of bootstrap 3 back in bootstrap 4 which automatically resizes the image inside a column and does a proper border effect.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qK42fUu.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in Bootstrap4 like this;

```
<img src="..." alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
```

From the [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/)